# Need help programming a word game

Tags: java

I am getting an error message in Eclipse:

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Player.

I have created an object Player.  The user through the JOptionPane enters how many players they want.  I am trying to store the players names in an array.

```
 public class Project3 {
 public static void main(String[] args){

  String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of players: ");
  int numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(input);
  Player nameOfPlayers;

  for(int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++){
   nameOfPlayers[i] = new Player(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of players: "));
   if (input == null || input.equals(" ")) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must enter valid name!!!");

  }

 }
```

Here's is my Class Player:

```
public class Player {
 private String name;

 public Player(String name){
  if(name == null || name.equals(" "))
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must enter a name. ");

  this.name = name;

 }


 public void addWord(Word w){

 }
 public int getScore(){

 }
}
```

Comment: "I am getting an error message in Eclipse" isn't very specific.

Comment: I edited the post and included the error message.  The message stated, "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Player."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the old value of `input` (from when you were asking for the number of players). You probably want something more like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++){
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the player's name: ");
   if (input == null || input.equals(" "))
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must enter valid name!!!"); 
   nameOfPlayers[i] = new Player(input);
}
```

Edit: Based on the error message you posted, the problem is that `nameOfPlayers` isn't an array, but you're treating it like one.  Try `Player[] players = new Player[numPlayers];` instead.

Comment: I've made the proper corrections to the code but now I'm getting another error message in Eclipse.  The message states "Type mismatch: Cannot convert from string to player"

Comment: I have corrected what I was confused with.  I forgot to cast the string to player.

Comment: This wouldn't work, although it might compile. String and Player are completely different types :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't create an array. 
Maybe you mean  `Player [] nameOfPlayers = new Player[somevalue];`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing an ending brace (}) at the end of the first bit of code you pasted. You haven't closed off the `Project3` class properly.

Edit: now I know the error, `nameOfPlayers` needs to be an array for you to access it as an array later on in the code. You also need to size it to `numPlayers` on its initialisation.

Comment: I may have missed the other brace.  But the error message stated "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Player"

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `nameOfPlayers` as type `Player` - not an array of `Player`. It should be

```
Player[] nameOfPlayers;
```

You will need to initialize it as well before you assign `Player` instances.